# How the intensity of light is related to the light wavelength?

Tags: visible-light, wavelength

Light can be seen as a wave or a particle. Light as a wave is well described by Maxwell's theory. Light energy relates to its wavelength and momentum too. However, if we treat light as a particle what will be the relation between its intensity to its wavelength?

Answer (score 3):

Intensity can be viewed as energy per unit area per unit time. So let's think about what this means for individual photon.

We know that for a photon
$$E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

Therefore, if we fire photons at a rate of $n$ photons per unit time covering an area $A$, then the intensity is

$$I=\frac{hnc}{A\lambda}$$